# Jquery not appending for some reason

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
static render(Students) {
        this.Students = Students;
        $('#app').empty();
        for (let Student of Students) {
            $("#app").prepend(
                `<div id=${Student.id}" class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h2>${Student.name}</h2>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" onClick="DomManager.deleteStudent('${Student.id}')">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class='card-body'>
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class='row'>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type='text' id="${Student.id}-subject" class='form-control' placeholder="Subject Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type='text' id="${Student.id}-grade" class='form-control' placeholder="Grade Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button id="${Student.id}-new-grade" onclick="DomManager.addGrade('${Student.id}')" class="btn btn-primary form-control">add</button>
                        </div>
                            
                    
                    </div>
                
                </div><br>
                `

            );
            console.log(Student)
            for (let grade of Student.grade) {
                $(`#${Student.id}`).find('.card-body').append(
                    `<p>
                    <span id="subject-${Student.id}"><strong>Subject:</strong> ${grade.subject}</span>
                    <span id="grade-${Student.id}"><strong>Grade:</strong> ${grade.grade}</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DomManager.deleteGrade('${Student.id}', '${grade.subject}')">Delete Grade</button>
                    </p>
                    
                    `
                )
                console.log(grade)
```

For some reason the second for loop is not appending

I tried to console.log and it does show the grades. I tried different appending styles like after and prepend.

My full code is https://github.com/ProfessorSocks/week-12/tree/main/assignment%2012

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `id` attribute you're using for the outermost `div` element of each student. You're using the same `id` for both the outermost `div` and the elements inside the loop for grades.

It needs to be unique in order to work properly.

Here's the code that would make it work:

```
for (let Student of Students) {
    $("#app").prepend(
        `<div id="${Student.id}-card" class="card">
            <!-- Rest of the card content -->
        </div><br>
        `
    );
    // Rest of the code remains the same
}
```